# Nested templating helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am working on a problem to implement a helm chart with customize configMap and trying to populate the configMap based on the environment mode.

Values.yaml

```
externalIPService:
 ip: 1.1.1.1
 port:  80 

emsConfig: "receivers:
 otlp:
   protocols:
     http:
processors:
 batch:
exporters:
 otlp/ems:
   endpoint: {{ .Values.externalIPService.ip }}:{{ .Values.externalIPService.port }}
service:
 pipelines:
   traces:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
   metrics:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
   logs:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
"
```

configMap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: simple-demo
data:
  message: "{{ tpl .Values.emsConfig .}}"
```

The helm template output is a plain string and not a yaml content. I have tried *toYaml* as well but it did not help either. Could someone please help to find a way to do nested rendering and to be able to use the final output in the confiMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: simple-demo
data:
  message: "receivers: otlp: protocols: http: processors: batch: exporters: otlp/ems: endpoint: {{ .Values.externalIPService.ip }}:{{ .Values.externalIPService.port }} service: pipelines: traces: receivers: [otlp] processors: [batch] exporters: [otlp/ems] metrics: receivers: [otlp] processors: [batch] exporters: [otlp/ems] logs: receivers: [otlp] processors: [batch] exporters: [otlp/ems] "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this situation, you need to use `_halpers.tpl` file.

first, add this to the `_halpers.tpl` file:

```
{{- define "appname.emsConfig" -}}
receivers:
 otlp:
   protocols:
     http:
processors:
 batch:
exporters:
 otlp/ems:
   endpoint: {{ .Values.externalIPService.ip }}:{{ .Values.externalIPService.port }}
service:
 pipelines:
   traces:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
   metrics:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
   logs:
     receivers: [otlp]
     processors: [batch]
     exporters: [otlp/ems]
{{- end }}
```

the `values.yaml` file will look like this:

```
externalIPService:
 ip: 1.1.1.1
 port:  80
```

and the `configMap.yaml` file, will need to look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: simple-demo
data:
  message: |-
  {{ include "appname.emsConfig" . | nindent 4}}
```